# How to make AjaxEditableLabel to show TextField?

Tags: java, ajax, wicket

I have a `AjaxEditableLabel`

```
AjaxEditableLabel<String> task = new AjaxEditableLabel<String>("task", new PropertyModel<String>(getModel(), "task"));
```

Now what I am trying to do is on some condition this `AjaxEditableLabel` will render as `TextField`. By default it is rendered as `Label`. Say if the model `String` task is null or blank the `AjaxEditableLabel` will be `TextField` else it will be `Label`.

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Edit:

```
AjaxEditableLabel<String> task = new AjaxEditableLabel<String>("task", new PropertyModel<String>(getModel(), "task")) {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 40L;

    private TextField<String> editor;

    protected FormComponent<String> newEditor(MarkupContainer parent, String componentId, IModel<String> model) {
        editor = (TextField<String>) super.newEditor(parent, componentId, model);
        Object modelObject = getDefaultModelObject();
        if (modelObject == null || "".equals(modelObject)) {
            editor.setVisible(true);
        } else {
            editor.setVisible(false);
        }

        return editor;
    }

    protected WebComponent newLabel(MarkupContainer parent, String componentId, IModel<String> model) {
        Label label = (Label) super.newLabel(parent, componentId, model);
        if (editor.isVisible()) {
            label.setVisible(false);
        }

        return label;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look in `AjaxEditableLabel` it has two methods used for initializing the Editor/Label: `newEditor` and `newLabel`. In the `newEditor` method by default it sets the editor to invisible. Overriding these two methods and adding custom logic to show the components based on the model value should do what you want.

Comment: thanks, I have added the modified `AjaxEditableLabel` in the original post.